# connecting to mariadb via django on windows 7

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x, django-settings

I am trying to use the Mariadb as my primary database for this django application I am building.  I tried following the instructions on

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-mysql-or-mariadb-with-your-django-application-on-ubuntu-14-04

Although the link says its applicable to Ubuntu, I feel it can be applied to windows7 as well. I might be wrong.  I went to settings.py and changed the following lines:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'live',
    'USER': 'rdsuser',
    'PASSWORD': 'gz#]5p%DS2',
    'HOST': '172.19.45.116',
    'PORT': '3306'
}
```

}

I saved the above changes, then cd back to my project directory with manage.py in it, and typed

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

and get the message "No changes detected".  Ok, weird.  I then went back over to my settings.py and noticed this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'scovilleapp', #name of the app I added
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
```

]

Everything looks good.

Then I went back to the super folder (the one with manage.py in it) and typed

```
python manage.py migrate
```

But I get this error:

```
django.db.migrations.exceptions.MigrationSchemaMissing: Unable to create the django_migrations table <<1142, "Create command denied to user 'rdsuser' @SRP-WKSTN06' for table 'django_migrations'.
```

Do I need to ask my administrator to grant me permissions?  Im using windows7, python3, django version 2.0.1

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

1. Check if you are granted the required privileges
2. Check if the table django_migratiosn already exists in your database
3. django.db.migrations.exceptions.MigrationSchemaMissing: Unable to create the **django_migratiosn** table <<1142, "Create command denied to user 'rdsuser' @SRP-WKSTN06' for table '**django_migrations**'. (Names differ... you may wanna check)

Comment: sorry I misspelled migrations.  I will change it on the error above.

Comment: Cool ... and wanted to know if you are connecting to a remote machine for your database or is it your local machine?

Comment: Nevermind.  it had to do with permissions issue.  My administrator gave me the permissions and it worked.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Permissions is the issue.  Have your database administrator give you permissions.  Permissions was obtained from following the following link:

```
http://users.fs.cvut.cz/ivo.bukovsky/PVVR/prace_studentu/Django_and_Maria.pdf
```